# Creating a Corpus with Spanish Text in R

Tags: r, encoding, text-mining, word-cloud

Trying to do some text-mining and wordcloud visualization on Spanish text. I actually have 9 different .txt files, but will just post one for reproduction.

> "Nos los representantes del pueblo de la Nación ARGENTINA, reunidos en
>   Congreso General Constituyente por voluntad y elección de las
>   provincias que la componen, en cumplimiento de pactos preexistentes,
>   con el objeto de constituir la unión nacional, afianzar la justicia,
>   consolidar la paz interior, proveer la defensa común, promover el
>   bienestar general, y asegurar los beneficios de la libertad, para
>   nosotros, para nuestra posteridad, y para todos los hombres del mundo
>   que quieran habitar en el suelo argentino: invocando la protección de
>   Dios, fuente de toda razón y justicia: ordenamos, decretamos y
>   establecemos esta Constitución, para la Nación ARGENTINA."

The file is saved as a .txt file. Below is my naïve attempt to generate the term-document-matrix with the correct encoding. When I inspect it, I am not getting the text as it is in the original file ("constitución" becomes "constitucif3n," for example). I'm new to text-mining, and knowing that the solution probably involves a wide variety of co-dependent adjustments, I figured I'd ask here instead of searching for 4 hours. Thanks in advance.

```
#Generate Term-Document-Matrix

#Convert Text to Corpus and Clean
cleanCorpus <- function(corpus) {
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, stripWhitespace)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, tolower)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, removeWords, stopwords("spanish"))
  return(corpus.tmp)
}

generateTDM <- function(path) {
  cor.tmp <- Corpus(DirSource(directory=path, encoding="ISO8859-1"))
  cor.cl <- cleanCorpus(cor.tmp)
  tdm.tmp <- TermDocumentMatrix(cor.cl)
  tdm.s <- removeSparseTerms(tdm.tmp, 0.7)
}

tdm <- generateTDM(pathname)
tdm.m <- as.matrix(tdm)
```

Comment: Info about where functions `generateTDM` and `cleanCorpus` exist might be useful. They don't seem to be part of `tm`.

Comment: Hey, you're right. Will add code for cleanCorpus in now. generateTDM is a custom function as well - code is shown above.

Comment: Ah yes, hiding in plain sight!

Comment: Converting the files to UTF-8 (e.g., with `iconv`) may fix the problem -- at least if you are in a UTF-8 locale.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd What is a UTF-8 locale? I'm coding in R, using RStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Make sure the original text file is UTF-8 encoded. To do this, I had to change up my Saving preferences in TextEdit on Mac. This made everything work seamlessly.